# Qual diferença entre Preference e SharedPreference?

Tags: android

Vendo algumas formas de persistência de dados no Android, percebi que possui duas interfaces muito parecidas `PreferenceChangeListener` e `SharedPreferenceChangeListener`, que podem ser estendidas nas classes `Preference` e `SharedPreference`.

Qual diferença entre `Preference` e `SharedPreference` e suas respectivas interfaces citadas acima?

Comment: Tem um [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222931/difference-between-preference-and-shared-preference-in-android) no So-En sobre.

Answer (score 2):

### SharedPreference

É um sistema que permitem aceder e guardar, de forma persistente, valores referenciados por uma chave.

O acesso ao sistema é obtido através dos métodos `Context#getSharedPreferences()` ou `Activity#getPreferences()`, que retornam um objecto que implementa a interface [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Uma possível utilização é servir para guardar valores do estado da aplicação, na altura em que o usuário a abandonou, de forma a que esse estado seja recuperado quando ele voltar a ela.

[OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

Interface a implementar por um callback a ser invocado quando uma SharedPreference é alterada. O callback deve ser registado através do método `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`.

### Preference

É um sistema que permite unificar como as aplicações permitem aos usuários configurar características e comportamentos do aplicativo.

Para manter uma interface coerente com a experiência do usuário com outros aplicativos Android, são disponibilizadas subclasses de [Preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html), uma para cada tipo de valor, a serem usadas como *views* em uma PreferenceActivity ou num PreferenceFragment.

A classe Preference usa SharedPreference para persistir os seus valores.

[OnPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html).

Interface a implementar por um callback a ser invocado quando esta Preference é alterada. O callback é associado à Preference através do método `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()`.

### Referências

- [Configurações.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)
- [Preferências compartilhadas.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)